# Are water lines required to be secured to the wall at the point of exit?

Tags: plumbing, cpvc

There are several water supply lines made of CPVC that do not appear to be secured behind the wall at the point of exit (to supply water to a fixture). Are there any building codes regarding securing the water supply behind the wall? I'm in Virginia, USA.

Comment: Does the faucet or outlet have provisions to mount to the wall? Or could the pipe be strapped to the wall?

Comment: Are you asking because you feel that a contractor is doing something wrong or because you wish to make it more robust for peace of mind? If the latter then go ahead and secure it.

Comment: The fixture is secured I usually will strap if a long run to reduce water hammer.

Comment: The wall is already closed, so it would not be easy or quick to secure. CPVC pipe can be pulled through the opening in the drywall and pushed back again. I don't see any leaks, but I thought maybe the elbow should be secured to bracing or a stud. In the past, I've installed a pex -elbow-nipple assembly, and the elbow has two eyelets to secure to the wall.